# Should I throw moldy Strawberries away?

Tags: mold

Should I throw away moldy Strawberries or just cut the bad parts off? They aren't super bad but I am a little paranoid when it comes to mold.

Comment: Plant them inside until Spring.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The visible mold that you can see is the *fruiting body* of the mold, that is the moldy-equivalent to the apple; much of the mold penetrates into its food substrate like the roots of a tree.

Since strawberries are fairly porous, the entire fruit is almost certainly full of the mold, even though it is not visible.

You should discard the strawberries.

Comment: This raises a question for me, what differentiates cheese from strawberries in this case?

Comment: @DrydenLong Some cheeses are soft, and the mold can easily colonize the entire cheese; these cheeses have to be discarded.  Hard cheeses are not easy for the mold to penetrate, and so cutting off an inch or two will do the job.